# I want to create a table that gets images, extensions, and size of images, and put it in the table with PHP?

Tags: php, html, arrays, foreach

I'm new in this place of work. So I got strugle with something a little bit complicated for me.
I want to create a table that scan some dir, get an array only of pictures, get size of them, and extensions, and put them in the table. here something that I tried...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device=width, initial-scale=1.0">
                <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
                <title> Tabela</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1 align="center"> Tabela </h1>
<p>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Extension</th> 
    <th>size</th>
  </tr>
<?php

    $target_dir = "slike/";
    $images_scan = scandir($target_dir);
    $images=array($images_scan);
    foreach ($images as $image) {
        $file_name_array = explode(".", $image);  //expecting string?
        $n = count($image);
        $extension = $file_name_array[$n-1];
        $size = sizeof ($image);
        echo  '<tr><td><img src="$image"></td><td>'.$extension.'</td><td>'.$size.'</td></tr>';
  }
?>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: OK, but what is your question? Does the code work or not? What probelm are you asking us to help you solve?

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Read up on [pathinfo()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php) and [getimagesize()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php)

Comment: Btw, why are you putting the result from `scandir()` into an array? It should already be an array.

Comment: So you will have to discard the `.` and `..` folders and anything that does not have an extension you are interested in. Also [sizeof() is an alias for count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) You cannot beat a quick squint at the manual

Comment: The manual page for [scandir() has some useful example code that you should also have a look at](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php)

Comment: Ok, sorry I just came to SO, need some time to explore. Magnus Eriksson, thanks, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [glob](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) instead of `scandir` and you should use [filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filesize.php) instead of `sizeof` as it's an alias of `count`

#### Example code:

You should be able to make it work just following my comments inside the code.
Actually, you only need to change the folder at line 4 (mind relative/full paths) and `$supported_format` at line 20

```php
<?php

//We call the function to get an array of images and their data
$images = get_images_info_from_folder('slike/');

//We echo the table
echo html_table($images);


/**
 * Array with all the info about the images
 */
function get_images_info_from_folder($folder)
{
    $all_files = glob($folder . "*.*");
    $images_info = array();

    for ($i=0; $i< count($all_files); $i++) {
        $image_name = $all_files[$i];
        $supported_format = array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png');
        $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($image_name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
        $size = filesize($image_name);

        //Only add supported formats
        if (in_array($ext, $supported_format)) {
            $images_info[] = array(
                'Image' => '<img src="'.$image_name .'" alt="'.$image_name.'">',
                'Extension' => $ext,
                'Size' => human_filesize($size)
            );
        } else {
            continue;
        }
    }

    return $images_info;
}

/**
 * Human readable sizes
 */
function human_filesize($bytes, $decimals = 2)
{
    $sz = 'BKMGTP';
    $factor = floor((strlen($bytes) - 1) / 3);
    return sprintf("%.{$decimals}f", $bytes / pow(1024, $factor)) . @$sz[$factor];
}

/**
 * Builds an html table
 * It will work with any multidimensial assoc array with this structure:
 * $rows = array(
 *     array("col1" => "car", "col2" => "white", "col3" => "15000"),
 *     array("col1" => "bike", "col2" => "grey", "col3" => "800"),
 *     array("col2" => "house", "col2" => "black", "col3 "=> "250000") 
 * ); 
 */
function html_table($rows = array())
{
    if (empty($rows)) {
        return 'empty';
    }

    $html .= '<table><thead><tr><th>';
    $html .= implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($rows)));
    $html .= '</th></tr></thead><tbody>';

    foreach ($rows as $col) {
        //Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities
        array_map('htmlentities', $col);

        $html .= '<tr><td>';
        $html .= implode('</td><td>', $col);
        $html .= '</td></tr>';
    }
    $html .= '</tbody></table>';

    return $html;
}
```

---

Don't forget to add some styles to table and img (for example: `max-width: 100%`)

Comment: Thank you for quick answer! :)